# How Can I Upgrade to 11.10 from the Command Line?

Tags: 11.10, command-line, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my 11.04 Ubuntu operating system to 11.10, as the current system is not the most recent.

However, I cannot use the GUI to upgrade - as from past experience I have learned this - because my graphics hardware only works on 10.04 to 11.04 (non-inclusive) and from 11.10+. So once I can get to 11.10, I should be just fine.

Because of this, I need to find a way to upgrade the OS from the command line. Can this be done?

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64885/how-do-i-upgrade-from-11-04-to-11-10)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the Ubuntu help website](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OneiricUpgrades#Network_Upgrade_for_Ubuntu_Servers_.28Recommended.29):

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Also from the [manpage for do-release-upgrade](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/do-release-upgrade.8.html):

```
DESCRIPTION
   Upgrade   the   operating   system  to  the  latest  release  from  the
   command-line.  This is the preferred command  if  the  machine  has  no
   graphic  environment  or if the machine is to be upgraded over a remote
   connection.
```

Disclaimer: I always install a fresh copy (I tweak and hack things on my installs, so it would be more hassle to upgrade than start fresh), so I have never tried upgrading through either the GUI or the command line. But this is the official method of doing the upgrade so it should be fine. I'd still back up any important data first though.

Answer (score 1):

Try `do-release-upgrade` as root. That should upgrade the system.