# Update Manager won't let me update to Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64885/how-do-i-upgrade-from-11-04-to-11-10)

Today i was playing with an old netbook (Msi Wind U100) I have with Ubuntu 11.04... I've updated it to the last updates and rebooted... the problem is, I want to update from Ubuntu 11.04 to Ubuntu 11.10 but there is simply no option available at all...

And when I try with update-manager -d the messages that appears tells me that the versions that he is about to install is the Release Candidate version so I cancel it..

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: If you open your update manager and click Settings > Updates, then look at the bottom option, what is selected?

Comment: Normal Releases (I thinkg I translated it right :S...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `update-manager -d` tells the system you wish to update to the latest devel release, not the latest stable release.

To update to the next stable release using Update Manager, check your Update Manager settings (Software Sources, Updates tab) : The bottom setting is `Notify me of a new Ubuntu version`, and select the option `For any new verison`.

To update to the next stable release of Ubuntu using the command line, use the command `do-release-upgrade`.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a URL that is being listed as not found? Because I had problems upgrading recently and it was because URL's were listed for dapper-drake, which is no longer supported.

If it is a specific URL that is failing go into /etc/apt and grep for the problematic address. Comment out any lines that contain it and then run do-release-upgrade afterwards. Hopefully it will be fine after that.