# Proposal to update from 11.04 to 11.10 is not shown

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, installation, upgrade, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64885/how-do-i-upgrade-from-11-04-to-11-10)

I'm trying to update my Ubuntu from 11.04 version. But when I open Update Center there is no mention about upgrade to 11.10. How can I upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and run the following command:

```
update-manager -c
```

You should see a window similar to this:

[image]

Click on the 'Upgrade' button and start the upgrading process.

The [`update-manager` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/update-manager) states that the parameter is for:

```
-c, --check-dist-upgrades
              Check if a new distribution release is available
```

Answer (score 1):

Start Update Manager and check that you have it set to display new versions of Ubuntu. Click 'Settings' and select 'For any new version' like shown below.

[image]