# Upgrading Ubuntu from 11.04 to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, 11.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64885/how-do-i-upgrade-from-11-04-to-11-10)

I want to download the 11.10 version of Ubuntu, and it says that I've to burn a CD, or place it in a USB. My question is; is it necesary to do the CD or USB backup even tough I'm actually working in Ubuntu? Thanks for the answers.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/64885/how-do-i-upgrade-from-11-04-to-11-10 dupe of this question - see accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

You can upgrade inside of Ubuntu.

To do that, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and run the following command:

```
update-manager -d
```

You should see a window similar to this:

[image]

Click on the 'Upgrade' button and start the upgrading process.

Answer (score 2):

You could try `sudo do-release-upgrade`

This opens the update manager and at the top there will be a message asking if you want to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Once connected to the internet simply search update manager from the dash and Ubuntu should tell you that a "new release" is available and you should be able to go from there.
If this does not happen, try restarting and follow the same steps again.
hope this helps, 
Ross