# Ubuntu 11.04 update manager doesn show any upgrades to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64885/how-do-i-upgrade-from-11-04-to-11-10)

When i open update manager to check for new versions it doesn show the 11.10 upgrade, i've tried also with apt-get update and it says my software is up to date. Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type following:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

It should help you. If problem persists, write following to terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

*(if you aren't terminal-friendly, write gksudo gedit instead of sudo nano)*
and rewrite **natty** to **oneric**
and do this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```