# How can I upgrade from 11.04 to 12.04?

Tags: 11.04, installation, upgrade, release-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update manager doesn't offer an upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125612/update-manager-doesnt-offer-an-upgrade-from-11-10-to-12-04)

I am very exited about the releases and i do want to try to install it , but I can't see it , when I do launch update manager, there is no update available , the option about notifying me is ticket in the option . But no chance ! Any idea why ?

Plus i can read that a lot of people is having many problems during the upgrade , do you have any idea why?

I did not done any customisation about linux , but a lot of software are installed and I do not want to  install again

Comment: If you are on 11.04 you have to first upgrade to 11.10 before upgrading to 12.04.  Please see this Q&A explaining how to do this. http://askubuntu.com/questions/64885/how-do-i-upgrade-from-11-04-to-11-10