# No upgrade to 12.04 for UK?

Tags: installation, upgrade, grub2, 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No upgrade possible via update manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125693/no-upgrade-possible-via-update-manager)

I am running 11.04 linux ubuntu on my toshiba computer ( 32 bits  ) . In the settings for update manager , i did put notifying me for any new version , but since yesterday evening it's not showing me any release ! I do not know why?

I Did select main server , AND united kingdom server but no chance it does show it!?
I do not want to use the terminal but the interface , and i do not understand why?!
any reason?

Plus i do have a toshiba 32 bits, 1.8 hyper treading core 2 duo ( 1 processor but 2 virtuals one ) and 2 gb ram 833 ghz  and a 250 gb hardrive , and share graphics card. I was wondering if it will be slower if i do upgrade from the version as i am now 11.04 to 12.04?

It's running fast enough , and i do not want it slower but hud is a pretty nice  function.

Thanks for your future answer ,

Sign by a microsoft employee that prefer linux :)

Comment: you raised a previous question - is this the same? http://askubuntu.com/questions/125693/no-upgrade-possible-via-update-manager

Comment: it'is not as i do ask as well if it's gonna run slower  or not ? and the result for my previous questions is not working :(!

Comment: The way this site works is that you continually refine your question by editing until there is an answer you can accept.  Thus - can you either transfer information from your last question here and delete it or visa-versa?