# Should I upgrade from 11.04 to 12.04 directly or upgrade to 11.10 first

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, 11.04, installation, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I skip over releases?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases)

Upgrade manager is talking about doing upgrade 11.10

Can (and should) I go straight to 12.04 ?  If so how (online?) ?

Yup, I've backed up my data !  :)

I've looked at a lot of similar questions about 10 and 11 upgrades but none of them are quite the same as my question using the specific versions I've shown.

This question: [How can I upgrade from 11.04 to 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125693/how-can-i-upgrade-from-11-04-to-12-04?rq=1) seems to iondicate that I'll need to do the upgrade to 11.10 first.

This: [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases) also seems to prefer that.

btw this is one of three systems.  I tend to upgrade one system and the other two I do fresh installs as that's certainly a good option every year or two and gives great life span to older machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is to do the upgrade via 11.10. Currently Ubuntu doesn't support version skipping in this way. [See here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes)

Comment: Yes. Or you can do a fresh install. Usually I am doing in this way: 1. backup my /home/
2. fresh install
3. restoring /home/
4. reinstalling softwares

Answer (score 1):

You have to upgrade to 11.10 and then to 12.04.
because you can not upgrade to 12.04 directly.

[More informartion here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes).